# R: `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Tags: r, statistics, regression, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow the instructions from this tutorial to create a regression model and plot the results(https://rdrr.io/cran/kernlab/man/gausspr.html):

```
#load library
library(kernlab)

# create regression data
x <- seq(-20,20,0.1)
y <- sin(x)/x + rnorm(401,sd=0.03)


# regression with gaussian processes
foo <- gausspr(x, y)
foo

# predict and plot
ytest <- predict(foo, x)
plot(x, y, type ="l")
lines(x, ytest, col="red")


#predict and variance
x = c(-4, -3, -2, -1,  0, 0.5, 1, 2)
y = c(-2,  0,  -0.5,1,  2, 1, 0, -1)

plot(x,y)

foo2 <- gausspr(x, y, variance.model = TRUE)

xtest <- seq(-4,2,0.2)

lines(xtest, predict(foo2, xtest))
lines(xtest,
      predict(foo2, xtest)+2*predict(foo2,xtest, type="sdeviation"),
      col="red")
lines(xtest,
      predict(foo2, xtest)-2*predict(foo2,xtest, type="sdeviation"),
      col="red")
```

[image]

This works fine, but the above code is for a regression problem with only two variables. I am trying to extend this code for a regression problem with three variables. Below, I have tried to recreate the above code for three variables (x, y, z : the response variable is z and the predictor variables are x and y):

```
# create regression data for new problem
x <- seq(-20,20,0.1)
y <- sin(x)/x + rnorm(401,sd=0.03)
z <- sin(x)/x + rnorm(401,sd=0.01)

#put into data frame
my_data = data.frame(x,y,z)

# regression with gaussian processes 
foo <- gausspr(z ~., data = my_data)
foo

# predict and plot (this is where the error is)
ytest <- predict(foo, c(x,y))

#plot
plot(x, y, type ="l")
lines(x, ytest, col="red")
```

This produces the following error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Is there another way to specify that you want the predictions to be made using the "x" and "y" variables? I thought in R, you can use the `c` command for instances like this?

```
ytest <- predict(foo, c(x,y))
```

This prevents me from moving forward and making two individual graphs between the gaussian process (foo2) and both xtest and ytest, in which the confidence intervals are shown:

```
foo2 <- gausspr(z ~., data = my_data, variance.model = TRUE)

xtest <- seq(-4,2,0.2)
ytest <- seq(-4,2,0.2)

#first plot
lines(xtest, predict(foo2, xtest))

lines(xtest,
      predict(foo2, xtest)+2*predict(foo2,xtest, type="sdeviation"),
      col="red")

lines(xtest,
      predict(foo2, xtest)-2*predict(foo2,xtest, type="sdeviation"),
      col="red")


#second plot
lines(ytest, predict(foo2, ytest))

lines(ytest,
      predict(foo2, ytest)+2*predict(foo2,ytest, type="sdeviation"),
      col="red")

lines(ytest,
      predict(foo2, ytest)-2*predict(foo2,ytest, type="sdeviation"),
      col="red")
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: For the error check `summary(my_data)` --> there is one missing (actually NaN from `sin(0)/0`) --> different lengths. ps the `predict` statement requires a `data.frame` so when you just pass a vector(e..g `newdata=x`) it is likely ignored.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I removed the "sin" all together (e.g. y <-  rnorm(401,sd=0.03) ) .. and now the first part works fine. But I still can't make the first plot and the second plot. do you know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things in your code that need to be accounted for; there are `NaN` values which lead to different vector lengths, and you are passing the `newdata` in `predict` incorrectly.

Using your data and model:

```
library(kernlab)
x <- seq(-20,20,0.1)
y <- sin(x)/x + rnorm(401,sd=0.03)
z <- sin(x)/x + rnorm(401,sd=0.01)
my_data <- data.frame(x,y,z)
foo <- gausspr(z ~., data = my_data)
```

Notice at this stage that **400** data points were used by `gausspr` used instead of 401.

> foo
> ...
> Number of training instances learned : 400

This is due to `y` and `z` having `NaN` values which get automatically dropped. They are `NaN` when `x = 0` (to see run `y[x==0]` and `z[x==0]`) due to the `sin(x)/x` term being `0/0`. So this is giving a hint on where a different number of observations may come from.

Next you are using `predict` incorrectly. From `?predict.gausspr` newdata should be

> a data frame or matrix containing new data

But you passed a vector; in fact you concatenate `x` and `y` into one vector with `c(x,y)`. So change

```
ytest <- predict(foo, c(x,y))
```

to

```
ytest <- predict(foo, data.frame(x=x, y=y)) # or cbind(x,y)
```

Note that there are 400 in-sample predictions (`length(ytest)`) as one of the `y` values is `NaN` and so predictions are not generated for this value. To `plot`, the lengths of `x` and `y` are required to be the same, so the values relating to the troublesome `x=0` term must be removed.

```
plot(x, y, type ="l") # x and y are both length 401
lines(x[x != 0], ytest, col="red") # both length 400
```

There are a couple of further errors in the next chunk of code in your question.

If there was only one predictor, then

```
predict(foo2, xtest)
```

should be

```
predict(foo2, data.frame(x=xtest))
```

However, as `y` is also in your model then you also need to pass a, or some, value(s) for `y` into the `predict` statement. You need to think what value to use -- perhaps the mean?

---

A slightly easier workflow is to prepare the data before starting the modelling as this can give a bit more control in how `NA`/`NAN` data are treated. e.g.

```
# remove NA and NaN
my_data <- data.frame(x,y,z)
model_data <- na.omit(my_data)
# run model and predict
foo <- gausspr(z ~., data = model_data)
model_data$ytest <- predict(foo, data.frame(x=x, y=y))

# plot
plot(y ~ x, data=model_data, type ="l") 
lines(ytest ~ x, data=model_data, col="red")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am still getting an error at this line: predict(foo2, data.frame(x=xtest))  Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'y')

Comment: I still can't produce the two graphs : lines(ytest, predict(foo2, ytest)) AND lines(ytest, predict(foo2, xtest))

Comment: The relevant sentence in my answer is "*However, as `y` is also in your model then you also need to pass a, or some, value(s) for y into the `predict` statement. You need to think what value to use -- perhaps the mean?*". That is you need to include some value for `y` in `predict(foo2, data.frame(x=xtest, y=??))`

Comment: Have you worked with gaussian process regression before? Does the code you posted at the end seem mathematically correct to you? my_data <- data.frame(x,y,z)
model_data <- na.omit(my_data)
# run model and predict
foo <- gausspr(z ~., data = model_data)
model_data$ytest <- predict(foo, data.frame(x=x, y=y))

# plot
plot(y ~ x, data=model_data, type ="l") 
lines(ytest ~ x, data=model_data, col="red")

Comment: Do you know how to add confidence intervals to the final plot?

Comment: Re the code: the final chunk of code I added is the same as you have posted except that I have explicitly dealt with the NaN values myself instead of leaving it to the function. I tend to think of this as good practice. I do not know how to add confidence intervals (I have not used kernlab)

Comment: Thank you! Is there another package that you have used for this kind of work?

Comment: I have used stan.

Comment: I have heard a lot about stan, but I have never used it before. Is it more straightforward for multivariate gaussian process?

Comment: there are examples in the stan manual which can get you going but I wouldn't call Bayesian modelling in general straightforward

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I wish you could write statements in stan, the same way you can as regular R statements. The syntax of stan looks quite different.

Comment: Here is another question I am working on related to bayesian modelling in R, can you please take a look at this if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67764577/r-error-in-xi-xj-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator thank you